# How Can I get users likes?

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to build an API using facebook Graph, where I have a text field that I use to enter a facebook profile link, for example:  www.facebook.com/id_of_a_user/likes
and when I press a buttom automatically the app displays below buttom, a list with names and Id's of all this likes pages.

In this part of my code I do a request to get the data:

```
        var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + user_id + "/likes?fields=id,name&access_token="+here_my_token;

      var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

      req.open("GET", url, false);

      req.send(null);

      objetoJson = req.responseText;
      container2.innerHTML = objetoJson;
```

That works when I user my facebook ID or the Facebook ID of pages like this: facebook.com/enespanol
But, when I try to use a personal facebook profile of a random user like facebook.com/user_id I receive as response an empty json.
I don't know why that happens(I'm a begginer in development with Facebook API's), but, Is there a way to get that Information from a facebook user profile?

What I want to know is information about the pages that a user likes, just that.

Comment: It happens because you don't have permission to get it

Comment: No, there is no way to get that from just any arbitrary profile; the user would have to log into your app and grant it permission.